# How to hide data based on state name in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular 4. I am trying to hide some data whenever the state changes. How can I hide particular data based on state name in Angular 4?

Comment: Did you find the answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

This is the example template that hide or show base on your component's visibleState property. Hope it helps.

```
<div id="your-data" [hidden]="visibleState">{{myData}}</div>
```

Comment: Is visiblestate is a state name?

Comment: it should be in your component property

    public visibleState=false
then you can hide or show your data by change this.visibleState to true or false

Answer (score 0):

There are few options depending what you want to achieve:

1. You can use the hidden directive to show or hide an element
   `<div [hidden]="visibleFlag"></div>`
2. You can use the ngIf control directive to add or remove the element from DOM. 
   `<div *ngIf="visibleFlag"></div>`
3. Or you can use **ngSwitch**

Component code:

```
 export class AppComponent {  
    visibleFlag: boolean = true;  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngShow="isTrue"></div>
<button click="show()"></button>
```

in component

```
isTrue:boolean = False
```

in function

```
show() {
if (this.isTrue == False) {
this.isTrue = True
} else {
this.isTrue = False
}
}
```